# I try to create arraylist and try to store only string and integer object using equal or instance of method but can we do the same using Generic

Tags: java, generics

I try to create arraylist and try to store only string and integer object using equal or instance of method but can we do the same using Generic

Comment: what's your question? what have you tried?

Comment: The point of generics is that you can only store one type in a list.

Answer (score 1):

No you can not. Generics rely on inheritance to make code type-safe. You would need a common superclass. If you don't want to write your own collection, you might want to consider creating your own class which abstracts the concept of what you are trying to add. Let's say the String and Integer in your list represent Suffixes (just as an example). Then you would create a class `Suffix` that either holds a String or Integer and offers the common behavior on these objects you are looking for. This way your List would accept `Suffix` objects.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what is the purpose of this hybrid ArrayList? How are you going to name it? Anyway, back to your question, the answer is we can (in a way) but it's not desirable IMHO.

```
class Holder {
    String strValue;
    Integer intValue;
}
List<Holder> alist = new ArrayList<Holder>();
```

You get the idea. ; )

Comment: try to not declare an `ArrayList` directly (even if you can), use a `List<Holder>`and instance it with `ArrayList<Holder>`.

Comment: Yeah, Luiggi is right. I don't do it in real code. trust me I don't. : D

Comment: Good! If you don't do it, don't post it as an answer either, try to teach the right way to do the things :).